# How to efficiently execute multiple operation using SAS if

Tags: sas

Can anyone teach me how to rewrite the following command more efficiently. Basically, I want to execute multiple operations if a certain condition is satisfied.

```
data a;
set a;
if var1 > 5 then var2 = 5;
if var1 > 5 then var3 = 5;
if var1 > 5 then var4 = var1;
run;
```

I know I can rewrite it as the following. But is there any more efficient way to do this.

```
Data a;
set a; 
if var> 5 then do;
var2 = 5; var3= 5; var4 = var1;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by efficient. Computation wise your second solution is already rather efficient.

Comment: Using do end, the program is a little bit long and looks a little bit messy. So I am think whether we can write those multiple command in one sentence?

Comment: You could generate a function or a macro for repeated use. Other than that I do not see a more compressed version of the do group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be amazed if it made any measurable performance difference, but if you only have one block of conditional code and you really hate semi-colons that much, you could use `return` instead of a `do-end` block:

```
Data a;
set a; 
if var <= 5 then return;
var2 = 5; var3= 5; var4 = var1;
run;
```

When SAS reaches a `return` statement, it skips the rest of your logic for the current iteration of the data step, outputs there and then (unless you've used an explicit `output` statement somewhere...), and (in this simple scenario) goes straight to the next iteration of the data step.

In general, though, this approach is on par with [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) and should not be used under any circumstances.